# researchers are in the process of registering a world patent for Gene 0.4

Tags: discussion

[Israelis finds bacteria-killing protein, could replace antibiotics](http://www.haaretz.com/news/national/1.557677)

> The researchers are in the process of registering a world patent for
>   Gene 0.4.

Is this even a meaningful statement, or a symptom of the current state of reporting? 
If it is true, is this something for the community to take action on yet?

Comment: Generally patents are applied for, not registered. Also there is no such thing as a "world patent" although there is an international application. My opinion is that medical researchers creating a new medications should apply for patents.